# Is it possible to change the icon for a bookmark folder in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a number of bookmarks in chrome that I have on the bookmarks bar with no text. I have found online tutorials to changing the bookmark icons. However, I cannot figure out how to change the icons of the folders.
[image: no labels]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still no provision to change the Bookmark Folders' Icon as per chrome [forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JRw5QDT3T7U). There is a workaround proposed by **DominicCobb** in the link itself.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to create my own webpage of links, then bookmark that page.  This allows me to customize what icon Chrome uses to represent my "bookmarked" links.

There are weaknesses with my approach.  If you don't have your own server you may not have access to this document all the time, it may annoy you to navigate to another page to get to your bookmarked links... but this gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

There is something else that could lighten up things a bit (without actually removing or changing the folder icon), which is to add emojis in folder name, and it will show beside the folder icon.

*P.S.: I've tested it with Win 10, Chrome 71, Firefox 64.  So it should work well with updated OS and browsers..*

You can add them with or without text, just one for each folder or more.. It would show like this: [image]

**Here is a list** of some of the possible icons to use (just copy and paste from here directly if you want):

☺

☕

♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ⛎

⛵   ⚓  ✈                                         ⚠   ⛽   ♨

♿     Ⓜ      ㊙ ㊗            ⛔ ✳ ❇ ❎ ✅ ✴          ➿ ♻

⭐ ☀ ⛅ ☁ ⚡ ☔ ❄ ⛄

—   /  — ⛄  —

☎               ⏳ ⌛ ⏰ ⌚

⛪       ⛺            ⛲

⚽ ⚾     ⛳

❤

✉                        ✂   ✒ ✏

✨                  ✊ ✌  ✋        ☝

❌ ❗ ❓ ❕ ❔ ⭕                               ✖ ➕ ➖ ➗ ♠ ♥ ♣ ♦   ✔ ☑   ➰ 〰 〽  ◼ ◻ ◾ ◽ ▪ ▫    ⚫ ⚪    ⬜ ⬛

◀ ▶   ℹ ⏪ ⏩ ⏫ ⏬